# Set WinForm Show Date from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

C#/MySQL - Set WinForm Access Date MySQL

So I created a MySQL Database which my form is able to access & login to. My goal for it is to be able to pull information from the MySQL Database into the form as a label (I know easy right?).

Example:

[image]

The hardest problem for me was figuring out how to store lets say a "Subscription" start/end date and be able to tell me on a label, how many days I had left on my subscription. All this using information for the database.

(Yes this database is for test purposes only no where near final.)

- Created a table called edata. 
  Created fields the program would use
  (Account Status/StartSub/EndSub)

[image]

My Question: How would I go about taking the dates entered and creating a value that I could use to show in the "Days Left Here" label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`New Table` (
  `ID` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45),
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45),
  `Username` VARCHAR(45),
  `Password` VARCHAR(45),
  `Account` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  `StartSub` DATETIME,
  `EndSub` DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Then query like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from edata where id = 1;";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        conn.Close();

        DateTime dateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["StartSub"]);
        DateTime dateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["EndSub"]);

        if (DateTime.Now >= dateStart && DateTime.Now <= dateEnd)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = dateEnd - DateTime.Now;
            label1.Text = "Active";
            label2.Text = ts.TotalDays + " day(s) left";
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Expired";
            label2.Text = "0 day left";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Worked perfectly. I made one small adjustment having to do with the decimal places. label4.Text = ts.TotalDays.ToString("#.#") +" day(s) left";

Answer (score 0):

If you can parse the values out it is pretty simple, for example:

```
string end_date_string = "2014-09-24";
string start_date_string = "2014-09-18";

DateTime end_date = DateTime.Parse(end_date_string);         // parse end date
DateTime start_date = DateTime.Parse(start_date_string);     // parse start date
TimeSpan dur = end_date.Subtract(start_date);                // total duration
TimeSpan timeleft = end_date.Subtract(DateTime.Now);         // how much time left until we hit the end_date

Label l;
l.Text = timeleft.Days.ToString();
// l.Text = timeLeft.Hours.ToString();
// l.Text = timeleft.Minutes.ToString();
```